# how do I get the names of unique categories

Tags: java, android, arraylist, unique

I have an `ArrayList` in which I have following details for each and every record, like: `Name` and `Category`

where, **Name** is Food Item name and **Category** is Food Item Category

So in an **Arraylist** I have `multiple food items for`same Category`, like:

```
Item Name : Samosa
Item Category : Appetizer

Item Name : Cold Drink
Item Category : Drinks

Item Name : Fruit Juice
Item Category : Drinks
```

Now I just want to get name of unique categories only

Here is my code:

```
Checkout checkOut = new Checkout();
checkOut.setName(strName);
checkOut.setCategory(strCategory);

checkOutArrayList.add(checkOut);
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Title of question differs from what you are trying to do in your code. I am confused... :/

Comment: how do i get name of unique categories ?

Comment: Add your categories into a Set, e.g. [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) which won't allow duplicates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could collect the categories into a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html). Using s [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) has a nice bonus in this case, as it will also sort the categories alphabetically, which is probably appropriate for a GUI that needs to display them.

```
Set<String> uniqueCategories = new TreeSet<>();

// Accumulate the unique categories
// Note that Set.add will do nothing if the item is already contained in the Set.
for(Checkout c : checkOutArrayList) {
    uniqueCategories.add(c.getCategory());
}

// Print them all out (just an example)
for (String category : uniqueCategories) {
    System.out.println(category);
}
```

EDIT:
If you're using Java 8, you could use the streaming syntax:

```
Set<String> uniqueCategories = 
    checkOutArrayList.stream()
                     .map(Checkout::getCategory)
                     .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Or, if you want to collect it into a `TreeSet` and get the result sorted off the bat:

```
Set<String> uniqueCategories = 
    checkOutArrayList.stream()
                     .map(Checkout::getCategory)
                     .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));
```

Comment: thank you so much, what if i want to know number of unique categories like : 2

Comment: @Oreo a Set is still a Collection - just call its `size()` method.

Comment: last question, i made uniqueCategories global but unable to use String category as global in my class, getting: category cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: @Oreo it's quite hard to understand the full problem from a short comment. Please post a new question with your actual code and the exact error you're getting.